# Maven android build gives compile time errors as if it's building with -target=1.5

Tags: android, maven, java, java-6, java-5

During my maven build I'm getting errors like this:

[ERROR] /sandbox/mobile-apps/quickdroid/test/src/com/xxx/MyActivity.java:[14,21] java.util.LinkedHashMap.Entry has private access in java.util.LinkedHashMap

I created a simple test project with one class. This error corresponds to this code:

```
        LinkedHashMap.Entry<String, Object> test;
```

Intellij compiles this code just fine.  If I change the -target=1.5 in my intellij javac parameters then I get the same error.  Below in my pom.xml I've specified target 1.6 and verified with the -X parameter that maven is getting this setting. Why do I get errors as if it's still compiling target 1.5?

excerpts from maven -X output:
  1.6

.

[DEBUG]   (f) source = 1.6
[DEBUG]   (f) staleMillis = 0
[DEBUG]   (f) target = 1.6

.

[DEBUG] Command line options:
[DEBUG] -d /sandbox/mobile-apps/quickdroid/test/target/classes -classpath {...} -g -nowarn -target 1.6 -source 1.6

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.xxx.android</groupId>
<artifactId>test</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>apk</packaging>
<name>test</name>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <!-- platform or api level (api level 4 = platform 1.6)-->
                    <platform>11</platform>
                </sdk>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I downloaded the maven-android samples from jayway 
https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin-samples

I verified that I could build and deploy the sample helloflashlight onto a device.  I then added the offending line (LinkedHashMap.Entry<String, Object> test;) to one of the classes.  This gave me the exact same problem.  I also tried pulling the javac parameters from the mvn -X output and ran it myself.  This also produced the same errors.  So this rules out maven or android stuff.  I get the same error from the javac command.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Probably an [Intellij bug](http://teamsys.intellij.net/issue/IDEA-21410) and nothing to do with Android or Maven.